# domain class that accesses a legacy database throws an error when set as a field in another domain class?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to access a legacy database in grails and I am able to do crud successfully with it. This is what the domain class accessing the legacy database looks like:

```
class Login {

   Long accountId
   String characterName

    // some other fields

    static mapping = {
       id name: "accountId"
       version false
    }
}
```

I want to use the Login class in another object like so:

```
class UserLogin {
User user
Login login

static constraints = {
}}
```

However, when I run my app, I get this error:

```
 | Error 2014-10-02 02:02:57,624 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table user_login add constraint FK_tn46n0dpvxs543dgi3378wj1x foreign key (login_id) references login (account_id)
| Error 2014-10-02 02:02:57,625 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Can't create table 'kokoo.#sql-4e0_74' (errno: 150)
```

How do I properly use the Login object as a field of User? I have a feeling it's because of the mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok with mappings, but when you start an application Grails is trying to update existing database schema against domain classes. As you've used Login domain in many-to-one relationship, Grails tries to create foreign key for it on `login` table and fails due to some reason (e.g. foreign key already exists).

For legacy databases it is recommended to disable automatic schema updates by setting `dbCreate = 'validate'` for dataSource, see details: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#3.3%20The%20DataSource. You can support database schema consistency manually then or use [migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration%20migration%20plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess there's no way I could automagically do it.. :D